# Node doesn't allow if statements without braces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Something strange is happening. I just upgraded to node v0.10.18.. One of my tests was failing at an unexpected place.. And it looks like I can't do if statements without braces any more.

```
if(false)
    console.log('shouldn't be printed');
```

In the above, example the text will be printed even though the if statement failed. But not printed in the following tests;

```
if(false) {
     console.log('shouldn't be printed');
}

if(false) console.log('shouldn't be printed');
```

Is there something I'm missing, has this always been this way with node?

**EDIT**: I just noticed this only happens when using **mocha**. Code runs ok in node. Any ideas how this could be happening using mocha?

**EDIT2**: Thanks for the answers guys, my example was simple, and in reality mocha digs down into files in my directory but when I'm stepping through the code using node-inspector, I see that even those the if statement evaluates to false, it goes into the next line and executes the callback line, which breaks my call. I can't recreate it anywhere else but I'm dumbfounded about how it's happening

**EDIT3**: Alright guys, I can't recreate this issue other than tell you where i see it happening. I was just trying to do my contribution to an open source project here https://github.com/jugglingdb/mysql-adapter
And in the lib/mysql, towards the last lines (10 lines up or so)(linked below) where it checks for filter.where and filter.update, that's where the issue is happening. Tests will pass if i add braces and won't if I don't

https://github.com/jugglingdb/mysql-adapter/blob/master/lib/mysql.js Line 890 here

Test where it gets executed:
https://github.com/jugglingdb/mysql-adapter/blob/master/test/migration.test.js line 291.. It's not there but the check for err will return the error that line 890 is throwing

Comment: I think your examples are the wrong way round.

Comment: I'd suggest that you *always* use `{}` with `if` statements, but that's just me.

Comment: This could only happen if there's a semicolon after the `if(false)`. You sure this is your exact code?

Comment: Show the exact code. There's no problem with your example.

Comment: If this only happens with mocha, then mocha is broka.

Comment: I am amazed this question received 4 votes. Did anyone bother testing it? The code in the question is clearly not the code the OP is running. Proof below.

Comment: Regarding EDIT2, you're saying that if you only remove the line break, it'll fix the issue? Can you give the actual code please?

Comment: @user2736012 Hey no it's the same regardless of debug. I'm just saying that I can confirm that the if statement evaluates to false and it still goes into the next line and executes it. I'm just working on recreating a simpler version of the code so that I can provide an example for you guys

Comment: What do you mean by "regardless of debug"? You don't have a `debugger;` statement in between there do you? If so, then that's the statement that is associated with the `if()` condition, making the function call entirely separate. Like `if(false) debugger; foo();` then `foo()` will execute.

Comment: @user2736012 I mean whether debugger is attached to mocha or not. I use node-inspector to step through the code

Comment: Oh, I was asking about the line break. Your question seems to imply that removing the line break solves the issue. Is that not right?

Comment: @user2736012 Sorry I see, yeah removing the line break solves the issue.. I really can't recreate this problem but it's happening. I came across this problem while trying to contribute to the jugglingdb/mysql-adapter project on github, the last lines of lib/mysql is where that if statement is. And tests will pass if I remove the line break

Comment: What do you mean by "tests will pass"? Is there some reason you don't just post a snippet of the actual code?

Comment: So if you replace `if (!filter.where || !filter.update)` with `if (false)`, you get the same issue?

Comment: @user2736012 Exactly, even if i put false, it won't work until I actually put braces around the if statement.. I can't recreate the issue on my own on a simple file

Comment: I'm going to assume it has something to do with a build process that is being used by the project, which is inserting a semicolon in that situation. Just a guess though.

Comment: @user2736012 YES! taht was the issue.. The project was using a project called [semicov](https://github.com/1602/semicov) and it was putting the semicolons.. Thanks a lot, feel free to add your comment as an answer.. Thank again for the patience, I was as frustrated and suprised as you guys were :)

Comment: I'm curious... your call to `UserData.update( ... )` is passing an object with `where` and `update` as the first argument, and a callback as the second argument. But the signature of `MySQL.prototype.update` seems to anticipate them as the 2nd and 3rd arguments.

Comment: ...ah you found it. Good. You go ahead and post the answer since you found the culprit. What's the point of that `semicov` project?

Comment: @user2736012 When running mocha, it generates a coverage map like [this](http://1602.ws/railwayjs/test-coverage/) When you mentioned it, I just remembered that project says it will break on certain cases where there's no semicolon, like this one

Comment: That's really pretty poor that it can't handle such a simple and common scenario. I'd never use such a project... but that's me. ;-)

Comment: @user2736012 Yeah it's not my project so I didn't make that decision. I just wanted to contribute something to the project since I use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project was using a module called [semicov](https://github.com/1602/semicov) and it was putting the semicolons after if line. It is actually noted in the project itself, somebody's broken commit somehow made it to the repo